# Order of elements in JSONArray

Tags: java, json

I'm parsing JSON files in Java using `org.json.simple`. I have a JSONfile that looks like this:

```
{
 "cells": [
    {
     "key" : "val1"
    },
    {
     "key" : "val2"
    },
    {
     "key" : "val3"
    }
  ]
}
```

If it is stored in a file named `path` and I fetch `cells` like this:

```
Reader reader = new FileReader("path");
JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse(reader);
JSONArray cells = (JSONArray) obj.get("cells");
```

can I assume that the elements in the JSONArray `cells` are stored in the same order as in the file (i.e. the first element in `cells` contains the value `val1`, the second element contains `val2` and the last element contains `val3`)?

Comment: Yep. The array `cells` will follow the same order, when it parses it as a JSON it should be sequential and read all values in order of the document without skipping anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a JSONArray is "an ordered sequence of values" (as can be seen in the [docs](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONArray.html)) you can assume that the array elements will be in the same order as read from the actual JSON file. So as long as your JSON file does not change, the read array will neither change.

But if it is possible I would advise against making your code dependent on the sorting defined by the file. I would consider that as bad practice.
If it really is necessary to define the sorting you could define the wanted sorting in your code by using the keys used in your JSON file. For example define an array `['key3', 'key2', 'key1']` and extract the values from the read JSONArray by searching for these keys and creating a new list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My _code_ is not dependent on the order, but it creates an output file containing a list of the indices of all cells that have a certain property. Since I have 32 000 000 cells in total, I want to keep this as short as possible. The keys are the same in all cells, and I have no power over the input format.

Answer (score 0):

While your answer is correct in case of ordering your are referring to the incorrect doc because the author asked about JSONArray that exists in the org.json.simple and not in org.json